# I get identifier out of scope at every break point in all solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

The solution is used by other programmers and they have no problem.
I tryied some advice to flag/unflag the optimization code in build settings. however it didn't solve the problem.
Also this is not project level problem because it is happens for all the proects in the solution.

Any idea? 
Thanks.

Comment: Not the answer to your question (I'll be watching the responses myself), but FYI on this useful feature for tracking objects that are out of scope: http://abhijitjana.net/2010/10/20/how-to-track-an-object-which-is-out-of-scope-while-debugging/

Comment: I don't understand why stackexchange was linked here.